# Panda dataframe index value as object instead of datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have downloaded some share price data via an API (from Alphavantage):

`response = requests.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=XXX")
data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data["Time Series (Daily)"], orient='index')`

and converted columns to numeric (df.apply(pd.to_numeric))

[This is output in Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvoia.png) - very standard matrix of dates and share prices.

I can't figure out how to manipulate the data (such as multiply `df.loc[df['1. open'] > 93, '1. open'] *= 2`) which is normally easy. I think there is something wrong with the index data. I have tried `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` to get it to timedate format and also tried renaming index. Also, the index column doesn't download if I try to move data frame into a csv file.

I think the issue is that the index data is still a string, but don't understand why it doesn't become datetime with code above.

Error message I get is ('>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int') but solutions from other questions don't work either.

Sorry for my long winded question and many thanks for any help!

Comment: Note that `pd.to_datetime` can often fail silently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the column is not `'open'` but `'1. open'`. (Edit: Okay, the question was edited to take care of this, but there's still an `'open'` remaining in there.)

Changing this, your example will fail with the error

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

which indicates that the columns do not contain numbers but strings (which you could also find through `df.info()`). You can take care of that by using `df.astype(float)`, or by specifying the desired types when creating the `DataFrame`, effectively using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['Time Series (Daily)'], orient='index', dtype=float)`.

In the first case,

```
df = df.astype(float)
df.loc[df['1. open'] > 93, '1. open'] *= 2
```

would achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks a lot - very helpful. you are right re open vs 1. open. After posting question I realised that I had not changed code and amended, but only did in one place. dtype=float worked a charm. Thanks

Comment: Great! If you found the answer helpful, you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).